# What is the term for the "s" that makes a noun plural?

Tags: terminology

Is there any term for the letter `'s'` that changes the nouns from singular to plural?

> Boy - Boy**s**

I want the term for that **'s'**.

Comment: Some people call it a *plural marker*. Of course, it's not the only one in English.

Comment: You can call it plural-s or plural ending.

Answer (score 5):

It's the regular plural suffix, *-(e)s*.

Answer (score 1):

To quote the beginning of the fifth paragraph of the article [Plural](http://en.citizendium.org/wiki/Plural):

> The English **plural marker** is represented in writing as -s,...

The quoted source is just one of many and you can do an internet search for "plural marker" to find others.